# DC / AC Inverter Principle of Operation

Tags: inverter

I am kinda new in power electronics and I have a task at hand that requires assistance.

I have an assignment to build a SMPS. My prof gave me a breakdown that once I rectify the Input from mains AC (230V rms), 50Hz to a DC (300V), I need to channel the output through a DC / AC Inverter. I have been searching the net for a pretty beginner level decent explanation on the principle of operation but I got confused along the way. I have come across the fundamentals of the SMPS Flyback Converter. Is that a better option to use instead?

Here is the block diagram from my prof

Rectify from Mains -> DC/AC Inverter -> Transformer -> Rectify -> 2 outputs , (12V, 5A),
Thanks in advance

Comment: You've got the right ideas, but you are somewhat fixated on the word "inverter".  Notice that overall the assignment asks for an isolated AC to DC switch mode supply.  (I'll write more later, although somebody else will probably beat me to the answer.)

Comment: Rectifed 230 V AC gives 323 V DC. Either voltage is enough to electrocute you so I am surprised that your prof gave you this assignment given your clear lack of understanding. Go back to your prof and ask him what safety precautions you should be familiar with when building the project.

Comment: Nowhere is regulation mentioned; will this be an unregulated power supply?   Other than attaching two wires, what is significant about "2 outputs"?

Comment: @Andy aka, this is supposedly my final year project, totally unrelated to what I have been doing at work , doing mechanical engineering. However before going back to the prof, Im trying to clear all my doubts so that I won't be left confused even further

Comment: @ Whit3rd, power supply is from the mains/ power sockets? this project is to power up a television that requires 100 - 120 watts. He wants a multiple output with both combined to be 100- 120 watts.

Comment: An SMPS Flyback Converter is what you are looking for and a company called power integrations have fully-fledged designs in the power area you are looking at BUT don't burn your fingers - it's easy to do!

Comment: @Andy aka, just to clarify the block diagram given by my prof is spot on? Hence should I just design dc/ac inverter ? Or create a design based on the Flyback converter topology? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it seems correct but the devil is in the detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WARNING - projects like this are dangerous to beginners and the foolish

Power integrations publish many designs like this one: -

[image]

OK it's a single 24V DC output but the transformer can be re-wound (yes nearly all these designs require a hand wound transformer) for two secondaries of 12V each.

[Premier Magnetics](http://www.premiermag.com/html/product-family/power-magnetics.html) (who supply the pre-wound transformers) are also quite keen to supply design notes that cover flyback applications and designs. Designs include power integrations, TI and fairchild chips and look good but I'm not a novice and there may be several things that can confuse a beginner. Here's a premier magnetic design that also uses the top-switch chip: -

[image]

I would certainly consider either of these two companys' offerings. Here's another one that is closer to your requirements: -

[image]

Comment: with ref to figure 3, may i ask, why do we need an EMI filter and there is no prior rectification for it to convert from an AC to DC first?

Comment: BR1 to the immediate right of the EMI filter is a bridge rectifier. You need EMI filters to reduce the noise generated by the high speed switching process (DC to AC conversion) from getting back onto AC lines and causing EMI to other systems.

Comment: that explains a lot. Thank you for your help I shall look into depth the concept of flyback converter and use the diagrams that you have provided as a base for my circuit!